# How to remove an NSParagraphStyle Attribute from a textView's attributedText?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to allow a textView to allow bullet points via a custom button by inserting the NSAttributedString `@"\u2022"`(unicode for bullet point) with an `NSParagraphStyle` attribute that has it's `headIndent` setting set to a certain point length to create an indention.

The problem is this: once I append that attributed bullet point to the UITextView's `attributedString` property, the attribute takes effect on all future typed text. What this means is that if you go to a new line (whether by pressing enter or just typing enough to hit the textView's horizontal bounds), it will always be indented. I do assign the attribute to the attributedString that just contains the bullet point, so I don't know why it's taking effect on all other text that is typed.

I can't think of any way of removing the attribute since it seems to no longer be assigned to a certain range because it effects all future text. And the only method I know to remove an attribute is if it has an assigned range, with `removeAttribute:range:`.

One other note: The attribute does not exist in the UITextView's `typingAttributes` property.

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *bulletString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\u2022"];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
[style setFirstLineHeadIndent:25.0];
[bulletString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:NSMakeRange(0.0, [bulletString.string length])];

NSMutableAttributedString *textViewText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.textView.attributedText];
[textViewText appendAttributedString:bulletString];
 self.textView.attributedText = textViewText;
```

**Summary**: NSAttributedString with NSParagraphStyle attribute appended to textView's text. Attribute effects all future text typed despite being assigned to specific range upon it's creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, paragraph styles apply to paragraphs. A paragraph is made of all the characters between newlines (or the beginning or end of the string). A paragraph style is defined by the effective style of the first character of the paragraph. So in this text:

```
A bcdef
G hijkl
```

only the effective paragraph style applied to `A` and `G` matter. The rest are irrelevant.

Second, when you insert or append characters to an attributed string, the new text takes on the attributes of the surrounding text. Specifically, in your case, when the user appends to the attributed string, the effective attributes of the last character are applied to the appended character.

So, you append `@"\u2022"` and assign it some attributes. Then someone types "A." That A now has all the same attributes as the bullet. Continue.

You need to make sure that the paragraph style is removed from the text sometime before the beginning of the next paragraph. Probably the easiest way to do that is to watch for the user to enter a newline and at that point assign the new paragraph style you want. Another approach would be to insert `@"\u022\t"` (i.e. add a tab after the bullet). Then assign your paragraph style to the bullet and remove it from the tab.

In any of these cases, though, the user could move around in the text and mess up your paragraph styles. You'll probably need to keep track of them and reapply them correctly in `textViewDidChange:`.

Comment: Thanks you, very helpful response. I seem to have gotten the desired behavior. If a new line command is entered (assuming the bullet button was pressed), I appended another attributed string (of just a single space, @" ") with a default NSParagraphStyle. This results in a new line unindented with a single space. The location of the styles is still a bit of a mystery, but they seem to be retained when text is deleted/added before the style, meaning bullets remain indented regardless of text edited before or after it.